# CNAME exception

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

I have a CNAME entry:

```
static IN CNAME c.commondatastorage.googleapis.com.
```

and I was wondering whether it is possible to make an exception for it? an extra rule that when the URI is static.domain.ltd/default/ CNAME is not applied?

I need to keep the same domain, but some content should be loaded from Google Storage, while some `/default` not.

If that is not possible, please advice. This is the only alternative I see so far:

I was thinking to use `server_name ~^static\.(?P<domain>.+);` instead with `NGINX` and then everything that does not contain `/default/` redirect to Google server. Is that a valid solution? would that dramatically increase server load? Though this makes Google Storage kinda pointless.

The reason for having everything under `static.` is the same origin policy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

DNS is for name resolution, it has no relation to URIs in HTTP.

Comment: Any alternatives then?